# ELK stack and web app on different servers, how to feed logs from later to former?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, nginx, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a website on digital ocean and on AWS I have ELK - Elastic Search, Kibana, Logstash - stack. I'm trying to understand how feed the logs files from web app to ELK stack.

- Is it possible to feed them via the internet between different servers?
- Do you I have to install nginx to be able to see kibana reports?
- Do I have to install ssl certificates for my AWS stack?

Comment: What is the reason for feeding the log files can you add in description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to you question is:

- yes
- no
- no

Comment: as for nginix, I mean to see them via the internet. so still not needed?